# Descartes and his taxonomy of ideas

Tags: epistemology, descartes, rationalism

Given the context of philosophical ideas such as [tabula rasa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabula_rasa), empiricism, and [rationalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rationalism), [René Descartes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren%C3%A9_Descartes) is known for his [philosophy of mind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_mind) and his attempt to analyze thinking as well as his advocacy of [innatism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Innatism) and rationalism. Among his writing is the notion of Perfection. According to his [epistemology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemology), is Perfection an **Innate idea** or a **Factitious idea** created by combining the idea of actual infinite with the idea of attributes?

Comment: The *Corpus Descartes*  (at unicaen.fr) gives 266 occurrences for the word. Descartes  maintained the old notion about "degrees of reality" or "perfection" and uses the word repeatedly in his *Responses*.  Finding a good quote requires some patience but "innate idea" looks as a sure bet.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the arrow to reward the contributor and the checkmark to select what you feel is the best answer.

Comment: Edited to avoid 'details or clarity' objection.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to the notion of Perfection in his philosophy, Descartes believed that the idea of a perfect being (i.e., God) is innate within us. He argued that we possess certain ideas innately, and the idea of God as a supremely perfect being is one of them.

In his "Meditations on First Philosophy," Descartes presents an argument for the existence of God based on the idea that we have a clear and distinct idea of a perfect being, even though we ourselves are imperfect. He contends that this idea could not have originated from us, as we are imperfect beings and cannot produce the idea of a perfect entity on our own. Therefore, this idea must have been implanted in us by such a perfect being, i.e., God.

To directly answer your question: According to Descartes' epistemology, the idea of Perfection (as it pertains to a perfect being) is an Innate idea. It is not a factitious idea created by combining other concepts. The idea of God's perfection is something we have without deriving it from our experiences or constructing it from other ideas.